# How to delete all objects except X from array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have an model schema that looks like this:

```
title: { Type: String }
description: {Type: String}
....
....
workingwith: [
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }
],
```

I'm trying to build an update function which deletes all objects in the `workingwith` array except by the one especified:

```
await Job.findByIdAndUpdate(
  request.resourceId,
  {
      $set: { positionFilled: true },
      $pull: { workingwith: { $elementMatch: { $not: { user: request.user } } } }
  },
  {
     new: true,
     runValidators: true
  }
);
```

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

This is what I tried already:

```
workingwith: { $ne: { user: request.user } }
////////
workingwith: { $not: { user: request.user } }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{
      $set: { positionFilled: true },
      $pull: { workingwith: { user : { $ne: request.user } } }
}
```

I came up with this by following along with an example for `$pull` in the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents).

Comment: Ja, I tried something similar to your solution before posting my question but it did not work because I had the syntax switched, this is what I previously had:`$pull: { workingwith: { $ne : { user: request.user } } }` lol